# Mysql store Procedure is not returning value by execution

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

This is the mysql query which I am running by using the sql console it's working properly but nothing shows in results,  but when I am running the query it returns results.

I tried many times but it's not working. why??

```
    SELECT U.assTo AS name , total_Solved, total_unsolved,total_Solved_date,total_unSolved_date FROM
   (SELECT
     assTo,
     count(*) AS total_unsolved
   FROM allinone
   WHERE assTo IN (SELECT name
                   FROM user
                   WHERE designation = 'Technical'
                   ORDER BY name)
         AND allinone.status = 'unsolved'
   GROUP BY assTo) AS U INNER JOIN
   (SELECT
     assTo,
     count(*) AS total_Solved
   FROM allinone
   WHERE assTo IN (SELECT name
                   FROM user
                   WHERE designation = 'Technical'
                   ORDER BY name) AND allinone.status = 'solved'
   GROUP BY assTo) AS S ON S.assTo = U.assTo
   INNER JOIN
   (SELECT
     assTo,
     count(*) AS total_Solved_date
   FROM allinone
   WHERE assTo IN (SELECT name
                   FROM user
                   WHERE designation = 'Technical'
                   ORDER BY name) AND allinone.status = 'solved' AND  allinone.assDate ='01/08/17'
   GROUP BY assTo) AS D ON S.assTo = D.assTo
   INNER JOIN
   (SELECT
      assTo,
      count(*) AS total_unSolved_date
    FROM allinone
    WHERE assTo IN (SELECT name
                    FROM user
                    WHERE designation = 'Technical'
                    ORDER BY name) AND allinone.status = 'unsolved' AND  allinone.assDate ='01/08/17'
    GROUP BY assTo) AS F ON S.assTo = F.assTo
```

**i am trying to Execute but not returning any result**

this is the full code for this table

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `show_all_report`() NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA SQL SECURITY INVOKER BEGIN
SELECT U.assTo AS name , total_Solved, total_unsolved,total_Solved_date,total_unSolved_date FROM
   (SELECT
     assTo,
     count(*) AS total_unsolved
   FROM allinone
   WHERE assTo IN (SELECT name
                   FROM user
                   WHERE designation = 'Technical'
                   ORDER BY name)
         AND allinone.status = 'unsolved'
   GROUP BY assTo) AS U INNER JOIN
   (SELECT
     assTo,
     count(*) AS total_Solved
   FROM allinone
   WHERE assTo IN (SELECT name
                   FROM user
                   WHERE designation = 'Technical'
                   ORDER BY name) AND allinone.status = 'solved'
   GROUP BY assTo) AS S ON S.assTo = U.assTo
   INNER JOIN
   (SELECT
     assTo,
     count(*) AS total_Solved_date
   FROM allinone
   WHERE assTo IN (SELECT name
                   FROM user
                   WHERE designation = 'Technical'
                   ORDER BY name) AND allinone.status = 'solved' AND  allinone.assDate ='01/08/17'
   GROUP BY assTo) AS D ON S.assTo = D.assTo
   INNER JOIN
   (SELECT
      assTo,
      count(*) AS total_unSolved_date
    FROM allinone
    WHERE assTo IN (SELECT name
                    FROM user
                    WHERE designation = 'Technical'
                    ORDER BY name) AND allinone.status = 'unsolved' AND  allinone.assDate ='01/08/17'
    GROUP BY assTo) AS F ON S.assTo = F.assTo;
END
```

why is it not returning any values

Comment: Your query is very large.  Can you break down your query into smaller pieces until you reach a point where everything works?

Comment: How did you execute the query/your procedure (exactly)? Are you absolutely sure that your first query, as it is, returns something and the procedure does not and that it is actually 1:1 the same code you are using (and you did not e.g. edit the `date`-values)? What DO you get? An empty set? Nothing? An error message? (Btw: if that is really how you store dates: you should change your `assDate`-column from `varchar` to `date`. It does not change your current problem though. Also, if your query gets slow in the future, you should read about `case`/`if` I guess.)

Comment: You have an error in your post syntax near "it's working properly but nothing shows in results, but when I am running the query it returns results"

Comment: So it shows an error and it does not return results. Why do you assume it is working properly? It is obviously not. So fix that error (or post it). Also please add the code you use to call the procedure. And make sure you actually have a procedure (e.g. do `show create procedure show_all_report;`)